# How to I get my 3D DEM terrain model to pop out of the page rather than sink down into it?

Tags: modeling

Not sure this is the right place to post this but any help is appreciated. I am trying to create a 3D model of a landscape using a digital elevation model that pops up out of the page. I have imported my DEM from QGIS into blender and it appears that the landscape is down in a sandbox (see photo). I am trying to make the landscape pop up out of the page, and not pop up from down within the box.

I tried using an expression in raster calculator to rescale the data so the minimum value in the DEM is 0, however that did not work. I have attached the histogram for the DEM below, it appears there are quite a few 0 values while most of the data lives between 500 and 2000. Is there a way to just trim the sides of my model? Or do I need to edit the data and have it in the right format before uploading to blender?

Any help, tips, or places to ask instead of here would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think I figured this question out on my own. Looks like the exported image file from QGIs had my elevation data within in, however in the image file there was a white border around my DEM, this was causing the model to look like a sandbox in Blender. Once I trimmed the edges in the file and re uploaded it to Blender everything looked normal.